# My test cases fail when run together but pass individually, at android studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, kotlin, mockito

> Test cases are running well individually but when I run all test cases together, some of them failed.
>
> I tried to use Mockito.reset function to reset the mocks but it is not working
>
> So, what can I do to reset the mocks ?
>
> note: I'm using mockito 2.21.0

```
class MainPresenterTest {

private lateinit var api: Api
private lateinit var mainViewContract: MainActivity
private lateinit var presenter: MainPresenter

@Before
fun setup() {
    api = Mockito.mock(Api::class.java)
    mainViewContract = Mockito.mock(MainActivity::class.java)
    presenter = MainPresenter(mainViewContract, api)
}

@After
fun resetMocks() {
    reset(api, mainViewContract)
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().build())
}

@Test
fun changeShiftToOn1() {

    Shared.shiftState = ShiftStatus.OFF
    val postShiftResponse = PostShiftResponse(200, "132")

    Mockito.`when`(api.startShift()).thenReturn(postShiftResponse)

    Mockito.`when`(mainViewContract.popupErrorMessage()).then { }
    Mockito.`when`(mainViewContract.showShiftDialog()).then { }
    Mockito.`when`(mainViewContract.dismissDialog()).then { }
    Mockito.`when`(mainViewContract.showProgressDialog()).then { }

    presenter.changeShiftState()

    Mockito.verify(mainViewContract, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).showConnectingBar()
    Mockito.verify(mainViewContract, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).startServices()
    Mockito.verify(mainViewContract, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).setStartShiftLayout(false)
}

@Test
fun changeShiftToOn2() {

    Shared.shiftState = ShiftStatus.OFF
    val postShiftResponse = PostShiftResponse(400, "132")

    Mockito.`when`(api.startShift()).thenReturn(postShiftResponse)

    Mockito.`when`(mainViewContract.popupErrorMessage(null)).then { }
    Mockito.`when`(mainViewContract.showShiftDialog()).then { }
    Mockito.`when`(mainViewContract.dismissDialog()).then { }
    Mockito.`when`(mainViewContract.showProgressDialog()).then { }

    presenter.changeShiftState()

    Mockito.verify(mainViewContract, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).popupErrorMessage(null)
    Mockito.verify(mainViewContract, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).showShiftDialog()

}
}
```

Comment: What are the failures? Which errors do you get?

Comment: please add the imports..

Comment: import io.swagger.client.models.PostShiftResponse
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.Mockito.reset
import android.os.StrictMode
@Roland

Comment: there are not errors, i just want to run tests together but not working  @Fred

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing some asynchronous tasks, then ensure that next instruction is executed after async operation is completed.

In order to wait for async tasks there is a library called Awaitility.
Here is it's link;
https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility.git

You can also use it as I've,
//SUT is System Under Test
SUT.login()

```
    await().until {
        SUT.coroutineContext.isActive
    }
```